# Css not wotrking with url routing

Tags: asp.net, css, url, routes

im using url routing its working fine but css not working

Here is my code

```
     <link href='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Style/admin.css") %>' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Style/reset.css") %>' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Style/OuterStyle.css") %>' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Style/mfv3_98290.css") %>' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Style/mfv4_98290.css") %>' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Style/demo.css") %>' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Style/slicebox.css") %>' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Style/custom.css") %>' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Try this <link href="../../Style/admin.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Answer (score 0):

use this,

```
<link href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Style/admin.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and put in your code

```
RouteTable.Routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.css/{*pathInfo}");
RouteTable.Routes.IgnoreRoute("{folder}/{*pathInfo}", new {folder="content"});
```